# Occurrences of value in column x greater than single value in column y - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

In order to report on appointments, I am trying to create a new column to add to the existing dataframe as follows;

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'appt_start': ['2020-07-02 09:00:00', '2020-07-03 15:00:00', '2020-07-03 15:00:00', '2020-07-06 04:00:00', '2020-07-06 07:00:00', '2020-07-06 07:00:00'], 
                'name': ['John', 'Mark', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'John', 'Sue'], 
                'appt_end': ['2020-07-02 12:55:00', '2020-07-03 17:10:00', '2020-07-03 20:25:00', '2020-07-06 07:50:00', '2020-07-06 07:20:00', '2020-07-06 09:05:00']})
```

**Logic to apply:**

count the number of occurrences where existing datetime in `appt_start` column is less than or equal to the current and all previous datetime in `appt_end` column

**Intended outcome**

```
            appt_start  name             appt_end      count
0  2020-07-02 09:00:00  John  2020-07-02 12:55:00          1
1  2020-07-03 15:00:00  Mark  2020-07-03 17:10:00          1
2  2020-07-03 15:00:00   Sam  2020-07-03 20:25:00          2
3  2020-07-06 04:00:00   Sam  2020-07-06 07:50:00          1
4  2020-07-06 07:00:00  John  2020-07-06 07:20:00          2
5  2020-07-06 07:00:00   Sue  2020-07-06 09:05:00          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Numpy broadcasting

```
m = df['appt_start'].values[:, None] <= df['appt_end'].values
m[np.triu_indices(len(m), 1)] = False
df['count'] = m.sum(1)
```

#### Explanations

Create a boolean mask using numpy broadcasting by comparing each value in the `appt_start` column by every value in the `appt_end` column.

```
>>> m

array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True]]
```

Now get the indices of the upper triangular matrix starting one diagonal right in the above boolean mask `m` with the help of **[`np.triu_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html)** with offset `1` and update the values in these position to `False`.

**Why are we setting these values to `False`?**

The main diagonal boolean values in the mask represent the result of comparing the `datetime` values in `appt_start` and `appt_end` columns in the current row and all the preceding boolean values from the main diagonal are the result of comparing the current datetime value in `appt_start` with all the previous `datetime` values in `appt_end`:

```
>>> m

array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Then take `sum` along `axis=1` to get the counts of the number of occurrences where existing datetime in `appt_start` column is less than or equal to the current and all previous datetime in `appt_end` column:

```
>>> df

           appt_start  name            appt_end  count
0 2020-07-02 09:00:00  John 2020-07-02 12:55:00      1
1 2020-07-03 15:00:00  Mark 2020-07-03 17:10:00      1
2 2020-07-03 15:00:00   Sam 2020-07-03 20:25:00      2
3 2020-07-06 04:00:00   Sam 2020-07-06 07:50:00      1
4 2020-07-06 07:00:00  John 2020-07-06 07:20:00      2
5 2020-07-06 07:00:00   Sue 2020-07-06 09:05:00      3
```

Comment: That was sublime! Could you please briefly explain your code

Comment: cheers. I seem to understand until the final part '...Finally take sum along axis=1 to get the counts..'

Comment: @windwalker you can imagine the main diagonal values in the mask as a result of comparing the current datetime in `appt_start`  with the current datetime in `appt_end` and all the preceeding boolean values as the result of comparing the current datetime in `appt_start` with all the previous datetime values in `appt_end`. Hope this makes it more clear.